# Change z arrangement of different modal subwindows

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I've two modal windows. One is already existent while the other is created. However, the newly created window is set *behind* the first subwindow.

How am I able to set the z index of the subwindows of the current UI?

Some code may help:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public void addSaveClickListener(SaveClickListener listener) {

    if (this.isSecure())  {

        PopupWindow sureDialog = new PopupWindow("", "Are you sure?", false, "Yes", "No");
        sureDialog.addSaveClickListener(listener);

        UI.getCurrent().addWindow(sureDialog);

    } else {

        this.getB_save().addClickListener(new ClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Close it");
                listener.saveClick();
            }

        });

    }

}
```

This is a method from the PopupWindow class. Note that the second window (sureDialog) is also an instance of this class and calls the method itself.

A screenshot might help:

[image: The second subwindow is behind the first even tough it was added last!]

Comment: This should not happen, can you please show your code?

Comment: @AndréSchild Done :)